# How to use arithmetic operator in golang html template

Tags: go, go-templates

I want to compare field 'FileSize' in my html go temple with variable 'minsize' in my code (.FileSize < *minsize). I have no idea how to do it. See below

```
{{ if lt .FileSize *minsize }}
<td style="color:red;">{{.FileSize}}</td>
{{else}}
<td>{{.FileSize}}</td>
{{end}}
```

Comment: Wont {{ if lt .FileSize .minsize }} work?

Comment: no, only 'lt .FileSize 9000' work where 9000 is what I have minsize set to.

Comment: Is minsize an int?

Comment: Yes, minsize is int as well as FileSize. But minsize is not part of pipeline like FileSize is

Comment: To be honest I am not a expericed go user. I checked here: https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/. In Example if I add a new int variable like Num and pass it inside data {{if lt 5  .Num}} is working fine. Sorry I missing something completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akama Razor tells me, that you don't need to use GO code here. 
it's much better to use JS in such situation.

Good luck!

```js
s = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (parseInt(s[i].innerText) > 123) {
    s[i].style = 'color:red';
  }
}
```

```html
<head lang="en">
  <title>123</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>1234</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    s = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      if (parseInt(s[i].innerText) > 123) {
        s[i].color = '#fff';
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answers the question and it's not "better" to use JS in that situation. That will depend entirely in what data he is using and the question doesn't specifies that.

Comment: Right, in fact I ended up with workaround using regular expression to replace string "-MINSIZE-" in the template  'tmplhtml = re.ReplaceAllString()'

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `*` in your `minsize` variable. If you are trying to dereference a pointer you have to do that in the go code, not in the template. That's why `9000` worked and the `*minsize` didn't.